# JS implementation equivalent to jQuery - div selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What's the equivalent in JavaScript of the jQuery lines below?

```
function foo(x,y){
   $("form[name="+x+"] input[name="+y+"]").val();
}
```

Comment: @LightStyle that skips the `form` part.

Comment: I edited, anyway it won't work because it doesn't exist `getElementsByName` in a `NodeList`

Answer (score 2):

If you're targeting newer browsers, it's almost identical:

```
document.querySelector("form[name="+x+"] [name="+y+"]").value
```

If not, you'll need to use some loops with `document.getElementsByName`.

Another way would be to use `document.forms`:

```
document.forms[x][y].value
```

Comment: or `querySelectorAll`, if that happens to be a radio button

Comment: does document.forms[x][y] fit for the edit I did? I mean something like this : <form name='x'><input type='text' name='y' /></form>

Comment: @DarioRusignuolo: Sure, try it.

Comment: IMHO you should us `document.forms[x].elements[y].value` instead of `document.forms[x][y].value`. It's more clearer what is does.